# Python SSL error on discord.py: ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1056)

Tags: python, python-3.x, ssl, certificate, raspbian

**The Error**

> ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1056)
>   SSL handshake failed on verifying the certificate
>
> aiohttp.client_exceptions.ClientConnectorCertificateError: Cannot connect to host discordapp.com:443 ssl:True [SSLCertVerificationError: (1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1056)')]

Full traceback (156 lines): https://pastebin.com/xmy4aYcM

**Debugging info**

I am running on fully updated Raspbian Buster with Python 3.7.3, on a Raspberry Pi 3.

Output of `uname -a`:

```
Linux hostname 4.19.75-v7+ #1270 SMP Tue Sep 24 18:45:11 BST 2019 armv7l GNU/Linux
```

Output of `lsb_release -a`:

```
Distributor ID: Raspbian
Description:    Raspbian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)
Release:        10
Codename:       buster
```

Output of `pip freeze`:

```
aiohttp==3.5.4
async-timeout==3.0.1
attrs==19.3.0
certifi==2019.9.11
chardet==3.0.4
discord.py==1.2.4
idna==2.8
multidict==4.5.2
pkg-resources==0.0.0
websockets==6.0
yarl==1.3.0
```

```
>>> import os
>>> import ssl                                        
>>> openssl_dir, openssl_cafile = os.path.split(      
...     ssl.get_default_verify_paths().openssl_cafile)
>>> os.listdir(openssl_dir)
['openssl.cnf', 'private', 'misc', 'certs']
>>> print(os.path.exists(openssl_cafile))
False
```

**What I've tried**

All my online searches give one of two suggestions:

1. Install `certifi` using pip

   - I have already installed it, and it does not change anything.
2. Run `Install Certificates.command` in the `/Applications/Python 3.X/` folder

   - This is Mac specific. In general, all mentions of this error have been on Mac only.

**Minimal reproducing example**

Create a venv, and install packages

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get install ca-certificates python3-venv python3-pip

python3 -m venv env
source env/bin/activate
python3 -m pip install -U pip
python3 -m pip install -U setuptools wheel
python3 -m pip install -U discord.py certifi
```

Open a python3 prompt, and run:

```py
import discord

client = discord.Client()
client.run("token") # error happens here
```

I do not encounter this same error on my PC running Linux and the same Python version and packages.

Is there a way to either

- Ignore ssl certificate validation checking (like the `--insecure` flag on curl), or
- Properly install the missing certificates?

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this:

```
import ssl
ctx = ssl.create_default_context()
ctx.check_hostname = False
ctx.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE

html = urllib.request.urlopen('https://blahblah.com/something', context=ctx).read()
```

This will prevent for validating the certificate. Otherwise, you will need to install it.